# i'm working in nextjs project and i want to use Cropper from 'react-easy-crop'; and i have some problems

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

i create a form input to select file, when the user press import, the model open with a cropper like that [the cropper modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty9ge.jpg)
then when i select the place i wanted i press crop the image displayed as white and some time black
depend to to the picture that i select
[result after position the cercle and press crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ipIz.png) 
[other exmple with other pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frcSX.jpg)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Vgq.png)

this is the code that i used

```
export async function getCroppedImg(imageFile, pixelCrop, width, height) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
      const image = new Image();
      image.src = reader.result;
      image.onload = function () {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

        // Create a circular clipping path
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(
          width / 2, // x-coordinate of the center of the circle
          height / 2, // y-coordinate of the center of the circle
          Math.min(width, height) / 2, // radius of the circle (half of the smaller dimension)
          0, // start angle (in radians)
          2 * Math.PI // end angle (in radians)
        );
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.clip();

        // Draw the cropped image within the circular clipping path
        ctx.drawImage(
          image,
          pixelCrop.x,
          pixelCrop.y,
          pixelCrop.width,
          pixelCrop.height,
          0,
          0,
          width,
          height
        );

        canvas.toBlob(
          (blob) => {
            if (blob.size > 1024 * 1024) {
              reject(new Error('The cropped image size exceeds 1 MB.'));
            } else {
              const fileName = imageFile.name;
              const fileType = imageFile.type;
              const lastModified = imageFile.lastModified;

              // Create a new File object with the cropped image blob
              const croppedFile = new File([blob], fileName, { type: fileType, lastModified });

              resolve(croppedFile);
            }
          },
          imageFile.type,
          0.8
        );
      };
      image.onerror = function (error) {
        reject(error);
      };
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
      reject(error);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
  });
}
```

this is the modal and function

```
import { getCroppedImg } from '../../components/imageUtils';
import Cropper from 'react-easy-crop';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
export default function Profile({ profiles }) {
  const fileInputRef = useRef(null);
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
const [croppedImage, setCroppedImage] = useState(null);
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);
  const [showCropModal, setShowCropModal] = useState(false);
  console.log(crop)
  console.log(zoom)

  const handleImageChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setSelectedFile(file);
    setShowCropModal(true);
  };

  const handleCrop = async () => {
    try {
      console.log(selectedFile)
      const croppedImage = await getCroppedImg(selectedFile, crop, 10, 10);
      setCroppedImage(croppedImage);
      setShowCropModal(false);
      console.log(croppedImage)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error cropping image:', error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
   <Head>
        <title>Fixili | {profiles.firstName}</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Site web pour tout deppanage domestique, Plombier, Jardinier, etc."
        />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      </Head>
 <div className="col-12">
                  <div className="card card-body border-0 shadow mb-4">
                    <h2 className="h5 mb-4">Select profile photo</h2>
                    <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <div className="me-3">
                        {croppedImage ? (
                          <Image
                            className="rounded"
                            src={croppedImage ? URL.createObjectURL(croppedImage) : avatar}
                            alt="avatar"
                            width={230}
                            height={230}
                          />
                        ) : profiles.avatar ? (
                          <Image
                            className="rounded"
                            src={`data:imageWebP;base64,${profiles.avatar}`}
                            alt="avatar"
                            width={230}
                            height={230}
                          />
                        ) : (
                          <Image
                            className="rounded"
                            src={selectedFile ? URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile) : avatar}
                            alt="avatar"
                            width={230}
                            height={230}
                          />
                        )}
                      </div>

                      <div className="file-field">
                        <div className="d-flex justify-content-xl-center ms-xl-3">
                          <div className="d-flex">
                            <svg
                              className="icon text-gray-500 me-2"
                              fill="currentColor"
                              viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            >
                              <path
                                fillRule="evenodd"
                                d="M8 4a3 3 0 00-3 3v4a5 5 0 0010 0V7a1 1 0 112 0v4a7 7 0 11-14 0V7a5 5 0 0110 0v4a3 3 0 11-6 0V7a1 1 0 012 0v4a1 1 0 102 0V7a3 3 0 00-3-3z"
                                clipRule="evenodd"
                              ></path>
                            </svg>
                            <form onSubmit={uploadAvatar}>
                              <input
                                type="file"
                                name="file"
                                accept="image/*"
                                ref={fileInputRef}
                                required
                                onChange={handleImageChange}
                              />
                              <div className="d-md-block text-left">
                                <div className="fw-normal text-dark mb-1">
                                  Choose Image
                                </div>
                                <div className="text-gray small">
                                  JPG, JPEG ou PNG. Max size 1 Mo
                                </div>
                                <button
                                  className="btn btn-gray-800 mt-2 animate-up-2"
                                  type="submit"
                                >
                                  Modifier
                                </button>
                              </div>
                              <br />
                              {UpdatePhotoError && (
                                <p className="text-danger">
                                  {UpdatePhotoError}
                                </p>
                              )}
                              {UpdatePhotoSuccess && (
                                <p className="text-success">
                                  {UpdatePhotoSuccess}
                                </p>
                              )}
                            </form>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              {/* Cropping Modal */}
              <Modal show={showCropModal} onHide={() => setShowCropModal(false)}>
                <Modal.Header >
                  <Modal.Title>Crop Image</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                  <div style={{ position: 'relative', height: '400px' }}>
                    <Cropper
                      image={selectedFile ? URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile) : avatar}
                      crop={crop}
                      zoom={zoom}
                      aspect={1}
                      onCropChange={setCrop}
                      onZoomChange={setZoom}
                      cropShape="round"
                      showGrid={false}
                      style={{ containerStyle: { height: '100%' } }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                  <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => setShowCropModal(false)}>
                    Cancel
                  </Button>
                  <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleCrop}>
                    Crop
                  </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
              </Modal>
</>
)
}
```

i try to change the zoom in  but nothing change

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who might find it helpful.

croppedImage is the cropped file, all you need to do is get the image url from the file and pass it to your img src to render. Also you want to increase the width and height passed to the getCroppedImg function, so the cropped image does not look pixelated.
Code snippet below

```js
const handleCropped = async() => {
  try {
    const croppedImage = await getCroppedImg(selectedImage, croppedAreaPixels, 500, 500);
    const croppedUrl = URL.createObjectURL(croppedImage);
    setCroppedUrl(croppedUrl);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

On the image you want to render like this.

```js
< Avatar variant = "circular"
sx = {
    {
      width: "120px",
      height: "120px"
    }
  } > {
    croppedUrl ?
    <
    Image
    className = "rounded"
    src = {
      croppedUrl ? croppedUrl : ""
    }
    alt = "avatar"
    width = {
      120
    }
    height = {
      120
    }
    /> : <></ >
  } <
  /Avatar>
```